# Hook useState with useEffect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect, use-state

I encountered this behavior. Two onChange are called in turn. One of them saves data to the state, and use the previus state to generate new one.

```
const onChange = (data) => {
    setState1((prev) => {
      console.log("onChange set state");
      return [...prev, data];
    });
  };
```

The other just prints something to the console.

```
const onChange2 = (data) => {
    console.log("onChange2");
  };
```

onChange and onChange2 called after click on button

```
<button
        onClick={() => {
          onChange({ foo: "bar" });
          onChange2();
        }}
      >
        2
      </button>
```

useEffect - saves data to state

```
const [state, setState] = useState(0);
  const [state1, setState1] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    setState((prev) => {
      console.log("use effect set state");
      return prev + 1;
    });
  }, []);
```

So, if you do not use useEffect (comment out), the console log, which in the first onChange will be called first, then the console log from the second onChange

[image]

[image]

If you uncomment useEffect, then the console will log from onChange2 first, then from onChange

[image]

[image]

Why is this happening, who can tell?

CodeSandBox: https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-hooks-sczvb

Comment: I guess it has to to do with setState being asynchronous:
https://iamsongcho.medium.com/is-setstate-async-b1947fbb25e5

Answer (score 1):

The call order of `onChange` and `onChange2` appear to change because the `console.log` in `onChange` is inside the callback passed to `setState1`.

If you move the `console.log` directly in the `onChange` you will see that the order is the same with or without `useEffect`.

```
const onChange = (data) => {
  console.log("onChange set state");
  setState1((prev) => {
    return [...prev, data];
  });
};
```

It's important to understand that when you call `setState` there is no guarantee that the state will be changed immediately, it's up to React to decide when to apply the new state and trigger a new render.

This is why the callback passed to setState should only return a new state and  not run any effects (such as `console.log`) since the moment this code is run is considered in implementation detail and could change with any version of React.

Comment: this is all clear, the question is different, why with useEffect we have different result

Comment: I don't think `useEffect` as anything to do with it, it's rather about `setState` and using a callback.
I've found that if the callback return the same state it keep running the callback synchronously but as soon as the value change, the callback is run asynchronously.
https://codesandbox.io/s/distracted-sutherland-qlcld?file=/src/App.js

Comment: But because of useEffect we get different behavior, how does it not affect?

Answer (score 0):

Expected behavior is `onChange2` called first, and `onChange set state` called  second whatever useEffect body is commented. because `onChange2` called right now. but `onChange set state` in setState fn called after rendered。

The "bug" looked is why `onChange set state` called first when first click. Hmm... find react computeExpirationForFiber. setState callback execute sync or async by different conditions. It's hard to read.